# Want to text input in custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm making ios keyboard extension and it contains view which has a `TextField`, but I realized this view is keyboard itself...

To input text in this `TextField`, what is the best solution?

That's all I can come up with at the moment(I don't know it's possible or not)

- Call native keyboard and get a callback on complete input. (It looks impossible)
- Use some awesome keyboard library that can be imported to view. (It looks the best solution, or do I need make keyboard scratch...?)
- Move container app and back on complete to input. (It's not preferred, because I want complete all on keyboard)

Probably, it's a very rare case, hope someone helps...

thanks!